# How to migrate customBackoff function that relies on errors -- aws-sdk v2 to v3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, migration, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

Migrating from aws-sdk v2 to v3. I have some code that utilizes the `customBackoff` function from the `retryDelayOptions` in v2. Depending on the type of error it receives it returns the respective amount of time to delay. My underlying code looks similar to this:

```
 const myBackOffFunc = (retryCount, err) => {
    if(err && err.code === "TooManyRequestsException"){
        return 100
     }
     return -1
 }

 const config = {
     retryDelayOptions: {
         customBackoff: myBackOffFunc
     }
 }

 const lambda = new Lambda(config)
```

How can I convert this to v3? I've migrated other configurations that are explained pretty well in the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/migrating/notable-changes/) but I can't for the life of me find how to convert this to v3. Any tip or details are very much appreciated!

Tried using `"@smithy/util-retry";` but I couldn't find anything that returned both errors and the retryCount. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way :/